# Create a URL with span class

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
<span class="semi-bold result-name">Search</span>
```

is a part of my code, basically using javascript - when you type in a text box the word search gets replaced with what ever is being typed in the text box.

is there a way to make this also update a php string?

```
$target = "Result here";
```

hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: You can't update any php variable on client side without using ajax.. Without using ajax you must use a form which submits the content you searched for and do whatever you like with the data sent

Answer (score 4):

short: no

long: javascript is client side while php is server side, all the php code is executed on the server before the page is served to the browser. after the the page has been served the client/browser executes the served html (result of php being executed on server) and javascript. since by the time the javascript is running the php is long done running.

although you cannot update a php variable you can use ajax to send a value back to the server using get/post. you can then use php to to assign the value to a session variable or store it in a database but it will be on handled by php on a different execution

**Edit:**
looks like the question was reworded a little, so here is some base code that should get you going in the right direction, also this code will work if pasted into phpfiddle.org

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['search'])){
    //do your code here
    echo 'results for '. $_GET['search'];
}else{ ?>
<script>
    //obj for ajax calls
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //onload
    onload = function(){
        //text change
        var e = document.getElementById('searchbox');
        e.oninput = myHandler;
        e.onpropertychange = e.oninput; // for IE8
    }
    myHandler = function(){ 
        http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open("GET", "?search="+document.getElementById('searchbox').value, true);
        http.onload = function () {
             document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = http.responseText;
        }
        http.send();
    }
</script>
<label>search</label><input type=text id=searchbox /><br />
<div id=result></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: This code is absolutely amazing. Too bad low count guys like us don't get all the upvotes for code like this. I'm building an application based on this code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could do that via ajax. Send your search term via ajax to a server side handling function which will then assign your search term to the $target. You may have to use onkeypress or another corresponding event in order to send your changed value to the server side and save it in the $target when each time the value is changed.